# using ignore_user_abort and set_time_limit(0)

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form in page1.php which both redirects to page3.php and also triggers an ajax post in page2.php (with no success function), page2.php might need to run for an hour, but the user doesn't need the results. I do need the user to see page2.php, but he might navigate away.

Do I need to use in page2.php these 2 functions? Or just one of them? Or none? I want to make sure the script in page2.php runs until the end.

Page1.php

```
    <form id="form" action="page2.php" method="post">
            <!--form input elements with names-->
    </form>
    <script>
            $('#form').submit(function() {
                $.post('page3.php', {
                    var1: $('input[name="name1"]').val(),
                    var2: $('input[name="name2"]').val(),
                });                                 
            });
    </script>
```

Page2.php

```
    <?php
            ignore_user_abort(true);  // Allow user to navigate away
            set_time_limit(0);        // Allow script to run indefinitely
            // a lot of code which will run for a while - between 3 minutes and an hour
    ?>
```

Page3.php

```
    <html>
            <!--some code here including links to go to page4.php-->
    </html>
```

I am asking partly because I thought there is no need for any of these functions, but was told to use them, but when I try using them, eventhough there is `die();` and the script stops, it still seems to be processsing something and I'm afraid because of this "indefinitely" it will be too much on the server. 
As I don't want to add unnecessary loads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need both of those functions in order to accomplish your current criteria, my suggestion would be to move this out of the http protocal. Depending on what your script is actually accomplishing if it requires no further interaction from the client it would be best used in the command line.

A theory of use would be to create a cron script that is called at the needed intervals, it would then access a queue which page2.php would populate.

If there is a queue available the cron script would process the information as it is currently done on page2.php. Since your script runs for a long period of time I would suggest using a locking mechanism for the cron, see php.net/flock for a simple file system lock. You check the file if its locked its already running.

Here is a simple example that you put into a standalone script for processing via cron:

```
$fp = fopen(DATA_PATH . '/locks/isLocked', 'w+');

        if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) { //locks the file
            $logger->info('Already Running');
            exit(0);
        }

        fwrite($fp, time()); //write our new time so we can inspect when it ran last if needed

        try {
            if (hasQueue()) { //checks to see if any jobs are waiting in mysql
               run(); //process normally completed by page2.php
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //something went wrong here could setup a log / email yourself etc..
        }

        flock($fp, LOCK_UN); //unlock the file
```

Comment: oh wow this is all very new to me, can you direct me to some links/ documentation?

Comment: updated with simple file locking example for how to setup a php script through cron and mysql usage best to check the documentation for your respective control panel and php.net/mysql for using mysql